# using builder in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am creating a form in rails (I have a user that has many answers and answers belong to users).

I have a `<%= form_for @user, :remote => true do |f| %>` and then embedded a form `<%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>` which get generated by the controller

```
if @user.answers.count > 0

else
  1.times { @user.answers.build }        
end

@userposts = User.find(params[:id]).answers`
```

the problem is I have tried wrapping it in a if statement (not well written I know !) but all I really want is to embed the answers form a certain number of times on the page 5 for example 
I can change the 1.times to 5 but this will keep generating new forms until they are filled in.

I only want them to generate 5 static questions the first time and then leave them 5 on the page to edit for any further visits.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers` in your user model?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using user has many answers, then we can do dynamically  answer form

try using gem nested_form(https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)